# Где найти template в Drupal 6.x зная url?

Tags: php, drupal

Есть страница на сейте с Drupal 6.x  типа

```
http://мойсайт.ру/node/номер_товара/edit
```

Как определить, какая страница (template, возможно и controller) отвечает за обработку node (центральной) части страницы?

Известно, что страница `http://мойсайт.ру/node/номер_товара/` генерируется в `мойсайт.ру/sites/all/themes/текущаятема/node-catalog.tpl.php`, но ни в папке, ни в ядре страницы, отвечающий за генерацию страницы с `/edit` нет.
Где искать? Как искать?

Comment: А что делать, если шаблонов с именами в такой последовательности нет вовсе?page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node-номер_товара.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В случае, если описанных выше шаблонов нет, стоит обратить внимание на установленные модули. Так, для моего Drupal 6 содержимым управлял модуль CCK (зачем-то криво установленный в другую папку). В нем, соответственно можно найти необходимые хуки (hook) и отредактировать выполняемые им действии при сохранении или изменении контента

Answer (score 1):

Изучите получше как создаются темы drupal.
Данный запрос обрабатывается в модуле `node` функцией `node_page_edit`
Темизируется в `theme_node_form($form)`

Для создания своей темы потребуется правка шаблона. 
При запросе, соответствующем вашему примеру, будет происходить поиск шаблона в такой последовательности.

```
page-node-edit.tpl.php
page-node-номер_товара.tpl.php
page-node.tpl.php
page.tpl.php
```

Где искать, отметил. Возникнут вопросы по правке, либо созданию шаблонов - обращайтесь к [официальной документации](https://www.drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7).

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий! А что делать, если шаблонов с именами в такой последовательности нет вовсе?

Comment: @Sergey Создать их, ясное дело. При этом настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией.

Comment: Если их нет, но при этом возможность редактирования продуктов на сайте работает, то совет создать их не подходит. Оказалось, что за форму измнения отвечает модуль CCK, который был каким-то образом установлен в папку с ядром и оттуда работал